# Android-Studio: How to attach a map to a NavigationDrawer Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This is my first post here and don't really know how to start..so excuse me if its too long..
 So...some days ago I started to work on a project in Android-Studio(my first one..so I don't know much about it and I am still learning)..What's all about..So its supposed to have a map activity + a drawer activity.
 I created a map project..worked it out..created a location listener..so till now my project had a simple map with a marker on my current location.
 Then..I moved on to my second objective..Having a drawable activty (right click on on project->new->activity->navigation drawer activity pretty much this) and then, I rewrite my manifest in a way that will overlay my map so the drawer would be first:

*Pretty much I want to attach my map to Home Button/Fragment so when I press my home button it will show me my map and when I press slideshow it will show "This is slideshow fragment"*

*Manifest*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.coffee">
  <!--
       The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
       Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
       location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
  -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>

      </activity>
      <!--
           The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
           (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
           Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
           You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
           sign the APK for publishing.
           You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
      -->
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
          android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

      <activity
          android:name=".MapsActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Now..I can't find a proper Youtube/Google tutorial that would show me how to "attach" my map to the first button of the drawer "Home".Found some things that said something like use a MapView or a MapFragment..but no tutorial about how to implement them to a button or what to do/to change..
(MainActivity)

```
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

And I'll put the link to the Git:
https://github.com/Devix71/CoffeeNOU

Any help would be much apreciated..And sorry if i put to much "useless" info.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow){
            //Here you can put you code
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        return true;
    }
```